# Unix understanding c after -size num

Tags: unix, size

in a unix command such as 
 **find ./ -size 1033c**
I understand what the find all of the size is doing but i tried looking at the man pages as well as on line and I couldn't find as to why there is a 'c' after the 1033, I am sorry if this has been asked before I tried finding the answer to this, but failed.

Answer (score 1):

Suffixes:

- b – for 512-byte blocks (this is the default if no suffix is used)
- c – for bytes
- w – for two-byte words
- k – for Kilobytes (units of 1024 bytes)
- M – for Megabytes (units of 1048576 bytes)
- G – for Gigabytes (units of 1073741824 bytes)

[Source](http://www.ducea.com/2008/02/12/linux-tips-find-all-files-of-a-particular-size/)

Answer (score 0):

It's a suffix meaning characters (or bytes).

The `-size` stanza of the `find` command allows you to do stuff like `10k` and `1m` (for sizes of 10,240 and 1,048,576 bytes respectively). The `c` (and `b`) is just a identity multiplier (i.e., 1).

See [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find) for more detail (search for `-size`).